# controlling the value of the xticks in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

so I am probably missing something *really* obvious but...

I use the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(t):
    A = 2409.505
    rho = 0.3260
    C = 0.00
    if C == 0.0:
        return (A*np.exp(-t/rho))
    else:
        return (A*np.exp(-t/rho)) - (C/r**6)

t1 = np.arange(0, 15, 0.01)
plt.ylim(-0.005, 100)
plt.plot(f(t1), 'b')
plt.tick_params(top = 'off', right = 'off')
plt.grid(linestyle = '--', linewidth = 0.05)
plt.show()
```

to produce the following plot:
[image]

However, I want the labels for the xticks to read 1 - 16. Can anyone help?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
plt.plot(t1, f(t1), 'b')
```

If you only pass a 1D array\list to plot. it assumes the x axis to be `1, 2, 3, ..` to to the length of your array\list

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the array t1 as your x variable in the plot function:

```
plt.plot(t1, f(t1), 'b')
```